# Is it possible to change window size with JQuery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I will create 5 buttons.
Example:

```
Button1's value : 640*480
Button2's value : 1024*600
Button3's value : 1600*900
Button4's value : 800*600
```

If the user clicks a button, I want it to change the browser window's size. I would like to do this via JQuery but JavaScript is fine too.

EDIT:

And how can i change windows' position for computer's screen.
Third question :) how can i create random number?

Comment: @Andrew i know this. But maybe JQuery haven't got function for this problem.. JQuery is a library..

Comment: 1. Please don't do this, it's really annoying to most users (unless you are setting initial size on a window that your code has opened). 2. If you must do it, in addition to `resizeTo()` you may want to look at `moveTo(), screen.availWidth, availHeight, availLeft and availTop` to centre the window once you've resized it - wrap it all up into your own custom `resizeAndCentre()` function. 3. Why is button 4's resolution out of sequence?

Comment: Do not Edit your question to keep asking more questions!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[window.resizeTo()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.resizeTo) and [window.moveTo()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.moveTo)

```
function changeSize( w, h){    
    window.resizeTo(w,h);
}
function movePosition( x, y){    
    window.moveTo(x,y);
}
```

Modern day browsers have settings that can prevent you have changing/moving/resizing the browser window.

[EDIT] Get yourself a good JavaScript reference. [Math.random](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

Comment: Chrome doesn't allow this

Answer (score 1):

In addition to epascarello's answer.

```
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*11)
```

That's the code for a random number between 0 and 10. Change 11 to whatever you want for an increased/decreased range.

Comment: That's the code for a random number? See this site: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp

Comment: @Andrew, I tested this code myself, use it regularly. W3Schools is *somewhat* accepted as a reliable source for information, so I used it. Other sites use this code as well. A quick Google search, and the first site provides the exact same info.