# Testing window.resize for a fixture with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

Im fairly new to unit testing and Jasmine. What I'm trying to test is to see if the window has resized, but I'm not sure how to do it.

I have tables that resize with jQuery and but the script only starts working when the browser is resized below a certain amount. What i want to do with jasmine is check if the browser window has decreased in size.

I tried doing $(window).resizeTo(1000,1000) but that doesn't seem to work with latest browsers? I tried using pop-ups instead but that caused a whole lot of problems.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649574/is-it-possible-to-change-window-size-with-jquery-or-javascript  This might help but I don't seem to understand what you need.

Comment: I'm not sure I got your question. You want to resize browser window using jQuery? I doubt that's even possible because JQuery only interacts with DOM within browser and not the browser itself. What your are looking for here is a Windows event that resizes application window I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot reliably use `resizeTo` to actually resize the window.

If you have handlers on `window.onresize` what you should be doing is manually calling the handlers you have that listen for a window resize in your test and use jquery-jasmine to see whether you meet your UI expectations.

As an alternative, if you use say modernizr or simply measuring the window size, use `spyOn` with `andCallFake` to mock them providing your custom size.

Comment: Thanks, ill give that shot, what ended up doing is putting a wrapper around the fixture and changing the width of it before i called the function/object that makes changes then testing against that.